# Fill form text box when dropdown selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form that is pulling data from multiple sources to intelligently prefill some defaults in the form. I would like to also prefill a "visit_price" text box that will be editable when the "visit_type" drop down is selected. This dropdown is a grouped_collection_select that is ajdusted via jquery by a Name search field (as per [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus-revised) and [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/102-auto-complete-association-revised) railscast video)

Below is the form view, model associations and coffeescript so far. I've also included the relevant html output.

**edit:**
To be clear, I'm not sure how to get the price that is associated with the client price that is selected from the dropdown.

Visit Block form View

```
<%= form_for(@visit_block) do |f| %>

  <div class="controls controls-row">
    <div class="form-inputs">
      <%= f.text_field :client_name, data: {autocomplete_source: current_user.clients.order(:last_name).map(&:last_name)} %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-inputs">
      <%= f.grouped_collection_select :visit_type, current_user.clients.order(:last_name), :client_prices, :last_name, :visit_type, :visit_type,  include_blank: true %>
      <%= f.text_field :visit_price %>
    </div>
    </div>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Models

```
class VisitBlock < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :visit_price, :visit_type, :client_id

  belongs_to :client

  def client_name
    client.try(:last_name)
  end

  def client_name=(last_name)
    self.client = Client.find_by_last_name(last_name) if last_name.present?
  end

end


class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :active, :address_1, :address_2, :city, :email, :first_name, :last_name, :state, :user_id, :zip, :client_prices_attributes
  has_many :client_prices, :dependent => :destroy

end

class ClientPrice < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :client_id, :price, :visit_type, :id, :default_price_id, :custom, :_destroy

  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :default_price


end
```

Coffeescript (so far)

```
jQuery ->
  $('#visit_block_client_name').autocomplete
    source: $('#visit_block_client_name').data('autocomplete-source')

  visit_types = $("#visit_block_visit_type").html()
  console.log visit_types
  $("#visit_block_client_name").keyup ->
    client_name = visit_block_client_name.value
    options = $(visit_types).filter("optgroup[label=" + client_name + "]").html()
    console.log options
    if options
      $("#visit_block_visit_type").html options
    else
      $("#visit_block_visit_type").empty()

  $("#ui-id-1").click ->
    client_name = visit_block_client_name.value
    options = $(visit_types).filter("optgroup[label=" + client_name + "]").html()
    console.log options
    if options
      $("#visit_block_visit_type").html options
    else
      $("#visit_block_visit_type").empty()
```

HTML output (so far)

```
              <h1>New visit_block</h1>

<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/visit_blocks" class="new_visit_block" id="new_visit_block" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="I4xbbvdswv18TtP4LWoZHo7udmABT0J/nvKEPLFfO5Q=" /></div>

  <div class="controls controls-row">
    <div class="form-inputs">
      <input data-autocomplete-source="[&quot;Client1&quot;,&quot;Client2&quot;,&quot;Client3&quot;]" id="visit_block_client_name" name="visit_block[client_name]" size="30" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-inputs">
      <select id="visit_block_visit_type" name="visit_block[visit_type]"><option value=""></option>
<optgroup label="Client1">
<option value="morning">morning</option>
<option value="Morning weekday visit">Morning weekday visit</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Client2">
<option value="evening">evening</option>
<option value="Morning weekday visit">Morning weekday visit</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Client3">
<option value="afternoon">afternoon</option>
<option value="Morning weekday visit">Morning weekday visit</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
      <input id="visit_block_visit_price" name="visit_block[visit_price]" size="30" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <button name="button" type="submit">submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you put a hook in your dropdown:

```
<select id="visit_block_visit_type" onchange="fill_in_price(this)"...>
```

assuming you have a price function that maps visit types to price, you fill with:

```
fill_in_price = ->
  $("#visit_block_visit_price").val(price($(this).val()))
```

Comment: thanks for adding this. The price and visit type should will be in the same database row. I'm not sure how to map that in correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Besides Viktor's answer is right, i believe it is much cleaner to leave the HTML markup free of any javascript code. I would follow this approach:

```
$('#visit_block_visit_type').change(function() {
  $("#visit_block_visit_price").val(price($(this).val()));
});
```

It's is quite the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, I’m having trouble understanding how to map in the visit price with the visit type.

Comment: There are n ways to do this. An ajax call and fetch the value from the database on type change. Prepopulate some element on your DOM with the type id and the price, so when you change the type, it searches the price inside the DOM, etc.